# Does Scala have "macro" definitions ready to use -- like LINE, FILE?

Tags: scala, macros

When you get a stack trace from exception you get files and line numbers. I need something like this for my reporting, so I could get to the cause very fast.

I am looking in particular for LINE and FILE macro. Is there anything like this in Scala?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such macro neither in Scala nor in Java. Of course the line number information is stored in the bytecode (also for debugging purposes) but there is no API to obtain it.

Stack traces with class names and line numbers are generated via native [`Throwable.fillInStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#fillInStackTrace()). Logging libraries might also use [`Thread.getStackTrace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace()).

In both cases it boils down to *parse* stack trace and find our current location. Note that generating stack trace is time-consuming and should be avoided.

Comment: I know there is no macro, but I had to name in some way macro :-) Anyway, this is very sad news -- I need it in a lot of places --  but thank you of course, very informative as usual!

Answer (score 2):

The [sourcecode](https://github.com/lihaoyi/sourcecode) library is based on macros and provides metadata at compile-time.

Example (taken from their page):

```
object Main extends App {
  def log(message: String)(implicit line: sourcecode.Line, file: sourcecode.File) = 
    println(s"${file.value}:${line.value} $message")

  log("foo")
}
```

This will print:

> /Users/jhoffmann/Development/sourcecode/src/main/scala/Main.scala:5 foo

You can use the implicits anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The is a project to provide a macro capability in [Scala](http://scalamacros.org/).

Perhaps you could approach the project team to discuss what you need

Comment: It is a project about Lisp-macros, so something way more complex, but it is very interesting nonetheless, thank you.